# how to use onkeypress for either email or mobile in the same field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have login page where user inputs email or phone. if user type phone i need to masking to US Phone number 123-111-2345 and also if user type email it should check for proper validation. how to do this for same field using jquery

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. Thanks!

Comment: And when the user's email looks like a phone number? ;) Seems weird to combine the two, I have not seen that yet on the web. What are the scripts you use when it is separate?

Comment: @epascarello: https://twitter.com/signup. ;)

Comment: @AleksandrM Yeah, but do they do masking? That was what I referring too. Plenty of sites let you log in with email or phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a jQuery function with Regular Expressions:
Just **the basics** for identify if phone or email:

```
//get Value from Input field.
var inputfield = $('.inputClass').val();

//regular Expression that identify a phone number
var intRegex = /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/;

//regular Expression that identify email address
var emailReg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/;

//if its a phonenumber...
if(intRegex.test(inputfield)) {

   //do stuff...
   console.log("is phone");

} else if(emailReg.test(inputfield){
  //do stuff...
  console.log("is email");
} else {
  //do stuff...
  console.log("enter valid email oder phone");
}
```